# UITextFieldTextDidEndEditingNotification not working properly in TableVIew

Tags: ios, ipad, uitableview, nsnotificationcenter

I have a tableView in which I use an instance of a custom TableViewCell.
In each custom cell, there's a textfield and a label.

Each time the text on the textField changes, I need to do some update in another textField present on the main UIView of my screen.

There are 6 rows in all

**ISSUE**:
The UITextFieldTextDidEndEditingNotification is triggered only on the 1st, 4th and 6th row on a first attempt.
Then on a 2nd attempt it would work only on the 1st and 4th.
When I DEBUG, it WORKS sometimes, but then it again does NOT work.

=> It's like it is working randomly.

I cannot figure out what's going on, anyone can help or provide some hint to track down the cause?

Comment: Check that you are setting your textfields delegate cell.yourtextField.delegate=self; If you are setting the delegate properly you should have no problem.

Comment: Shatanu this is PERFECT!! Thanks it solved my issue! Kudos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And you should prefer using the following callback method instead of UITextFieldTextDidEndEditing

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer solves the problem, but doesn't answer the question.

The reason why the `UITextFieldTextDidEndEditingNotification` wasn't working was because this notification only fires when the user finishes editing the field and closes the keyboard or selects another textfield.

What you should have been observing is the `UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification`, which fires every time the text changes.

Comment: Hi Nick, thanks for the nice description.
Infact it's the 1st of Shantanu which solved the issue I was getting, I quote: **"Check that you are setting your textfields delegate cell.yourtextField.delegate=self;"**

Comment: If you are using notifications like UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification then you do not need to set the delegate. You only need to set the delegate property if you are using the textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange: delegate method instead of notifications.